# Make many robocopy executes in one bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, robocopy

I am trying to create a .bat file that will copy many folders using robocopy.
However, I can't seem to make it work, eventhough the executing finishes with an "Ok" message. The files are being copied arbitrarily if lucky, as many are not copying at all!

I have checked the paths, the names... everything seems to be ok, help!

```
echo off
echo "Copiando ficheros..."
 
robocopy "D:\GESTION14\DatosA21" "D:\Qlik Sense\DatosA21" 
robocopy "D:\GESTION14\Datos21" "D:\Qlik Sense\Datos21" 
robocopy "D:\GESTION14\DatosSP21" "D:\Qlik Sense\DatosSP21" 
robocopy "D:\GESTION14\DatosASP21" "D:\Qlik Sense\DatosASP21" 
robocopy "D:\GESTION14\DatosIN21" "D:\Qlik Sense\DatosIN21"
robocopy "D:\GESTION14\DatosAIN21" "D:\Qlik Sense\DatosAIN21" 


if errorlevel 4 echo Error en la copia & goto Copia_Error
if errorlevel 1 echo Copia finalizada correctamente & goto Copia_Correcta
if errorlevel 0 echo Copia finalizada correctamente sin cambios & goto Copia_Correcta_Sin_Cambios
 
:Copia_Error
msg * Se ha producido un error en la copia.
pause
exit
 
:Copia_Correcta
msg * Copia realizada correctamente.
pause
exit
 
:Copia_Correcta_Sin_Cambios
msg * Copia realizada correctamente sin cambios.
pause
exit
```

Comment: You are checking errorlevel for the last command only. But besides that, you could just run a for loop to make it easier. But I need to understand what these are? Are these folders?

Comment: I'd also ask why you're using `robocopy.exe` when you're clearly not using any of its options. Please open a Command Prompt window, type `help robocopy`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the output.